# Why cant I access glassfish server from my local network

Tags: java, networking, netbeans, glassfish

I installed netbeans with glassfish server for an ejb project.

If I enter `localhost:9999/myproject/` in my browser its works.

When I also tried `mylocalip:9999/myproject/` it worked.

But when I try to connect from another PC or phone on the same network I can't reach my project (pc and phone connect via wifi)

notes:

I connect to the network via wifi to router. 
I turn off the firewall and add rule in the firewall with port 9999 but doesn't work.
I can't ping other devices on the wireless network.
i try to ping the address of another pc from my pc is work.
my system is windows 7
netbeans 8.0.1
glassfish 4.1

Answer (score 1):

As I see you are trying to host a project on your LAN network, so all devices on your LAN can connect to it. Firstly check your settings for your server and make sure everything is alright. I suggest you take a look at Configuration > HTTP Service > HTTP Listeners and check what it is bound to. If the IP address is not your network interface address or 0.0.0.0 then change the IP address to your network interface address or 0.0.0.0. Note that after editing any settings you must restart the server. Also make sure that all are on the same LAN network (connected to the same router / Wi-Fi network). Then to connect to it hold the Windows key and press R. Run window should appear. In there type `cmd` and hit enter, then in the black window type `ipconfig/all` and look for a Local Area Connetion or Wireless LAN Adapter. At one of these there should be an IPV4 address that starts with `192.168`. Use that to connect (in your case `192.168.x.xxx:9999/myproject/`).

Hope I helped!

Comment: i do every things you have said but nothing change note that i can ping from my pc other devices but from other pc i can't ping my pc , which hold the server and project, any help @Matei Trandafir

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue..

First make sure you can ping your server

```
ping 192.168.xxx.xxx:9999
```

The make sure you have no blocking firewall (on ubuntu)

```
sudo ufw status
```

Check if your port is allowed (9999 ALLOW).
If you can't see it on the list, add it:

```
sudo ufw allow 9999
```

Happy glassfishing :)